# Как добавить третий зависимый select

Tags: javascript, select

Есть 2 селектора со странами и городами, как добавить третий в котором будут районы, что бы при выборе города, появлялся третий select с выбором районов?

```
<select id="countries-select"></select>
<select id="cities-select"></select>

<script>
    var countriesSelect = document.querySelector('#countries-select');
    var citiesSelect = document.querySelector('#cities-select');

    var data = {
        Россия: ['Москва', 'Питер', 'Воронеж'],
        Беларусь: ['Минск', 'Витебск', 'Орша'],
        Украина: ['Киев', 'Львов', 'Одесса'],
    }

    var countries = Object.keys(data);
    addOptions(countriesSelect, countries);

    var defaultCities = data[countries[0]];
    addOptions(citiesSelect, defaultCities);

    countriesSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
        var cities = data[this.value];
        citiesSelect.length = 0;

        addOptions(citiesSelect, cities);
    });

    function addOptions(select, arr) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            select.add(new Option(arr[i]));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var countriesSelect = document.querySelector('#countries-select');
var citiesSelect = document.querySelector('#cities-select');
var districtsSelect = document.querySelector('#districts-select');

var data = {
  Россия: {
    Москва:  ["District R-M-1", "District R-M-2"],
    Питер:   ["District R-P-1", "District R-P-2"],
    Воронеж: ["District R-V-1", "District R-V-2"]
  },
  Беларусь: {
    Минск:   ["District B-M-1", "District B-M-2"],
    Витебск: ["District B-V-1", "District B-V-2"],
    Орша:    ["District B-O-1", "District B-O-2"]
  },
  Украина: {
    Киев:   ["District U-K-1", "District U-K-2"],
    Львов:  ["District U-L-1", "District U-L-2"],
    Одесса: ["District U-O-1", "District U-O-2"]
  }
};

function addOptions(select, arr) {
  select.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    select.add(new Option(arr[i]));
  }
}

function countriesChanged() {
  addOptions(citiesSelect, Object.keys(data[countriesSelect.value]));
  citiesChanged();
}
countriesSelect.addEventListener('change', countriesChanged);

function citiesChanged() {
  addOptions(districtsSelect, data[countriesSelect.value][citiesSelect.value]);
}
citiesSelect.addEventListener('change', citiesChanged);

addOptions(countriesSelect, Object.keys(data));
countriesChanged();
citiesChanged();
```

```html
<select id="countries-select"></select>
<select id="cities-select"></select>
<select id="districts-select"></select>
```

Comment: я изменил предыдущий массив на этот, но у меня не работает(

Comment: @ИванКолесо Код, я полагаю, Вы тоже изменили?

Comment: Нет, код я не менял, так как не разбираюсь. Мне нужно проделать тоже самое только со следующей парой, города и районы?

Comment: Я понимаю, что нужно добавить переменную с районами, а как дальше не понимаю

Comment: @ИванКолесо Как минимум, надо начать с добавления третьего `select`-а в html.

Comment: Я добавил третий select, присвоил ему id="areas-select" . Добавил новую переменную var areasSelect = document.querySelector('#areas-select');

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, все работает!

Comment: @ИванКолесо На здоровье. Успехов!