# Динамические списки JavaScript

Tags: javascript, select

Нужна система выпадающих списков, чтоб каждый появлялся только при выборе в предыдущем списке.
То есть, имеем Список 1. Он содержит три пункта. 
При выборе пунта 1 появляется Список 2. При выборе пункта 2 в списке один появляется список 3. При выборе пункта 3 в списке 1 появляется список 4.
В каждом из список n пунктов, при выборе которых так же должны появляться новые списки. 
Как сделать такую систему?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-select/948136#948136

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/780546/262779